# Answer question about commiting a crime on DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, dubai

I have a cheque returned police case in Dubai, U.A.E. 
In the DS-160 form, what should I reply to:

> Have you committed any crime?

How will they know about the Dubai police case?

Comment: is a "cheque returned police case" a crime? It's not a trick question. And lying about minor crimes will result in refusals when the minor crimes themselves would not.

Comment: Did you pass the check on purpose or by mistake?  Were you convicted (including pleading guilty or no contest or any other disposition that resulted in the imposition of a punishment)?  What was the maximum possible sentence for the conviction?

Answer (score 1):

**Have you committed a crime?**

**Is the "cheque returned police case" a crime**?

If so, the answer is yes even if minor. If no, and you haven't committed any other crimes, the answer is no. Lying will just make you less trustworthy and open a way to refusal.

US immigration authorities can obtain this information, so they will know.